# Is there a limit on the number of variables while using ovun.sample in R?

Tags: r, data-science, sampling

I am using ovun.sample for a project and my data frame has more than 150 variables, but misteriously when I use ovun.sample, the resulting data frame only cointains 29 variables. I do not find the error.

I am searching everywhere for the error but I got stuck.

Something to keep in mind is that, most of the +150 original variables are dummies and its multiplicatives against an original set of 13 variables. I generate the dummies (16) and the multiplicatives. The only variables that ovun.sample recognizes are the original 13 variables and the 16 dummies alone, not even one of the multiplicatives.